# Get total days in a list of dates C#

Tags: c#, list, date, sum

I just want to get the total days in a list of dates. Here is my code it is returning 10 days, it should print 4 days or so.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Initializes new List of DataTime Object.
    List<DateTime> Dates = new List<DateTime>();

    //Fills the List of DateTime Object.
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i));
        //Adds new DataTime Object in the list of DateTime Object.
        Thread.Sleep(1000); //Stop filling dates for one second.
    }

    //Prints the List of DataTime Object.
    for (int i = 0; i <5 ; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Dates[i]);
    }
    avgDate(Dates);
}

public static void avgDate(List<DateTime> Dates) {
    long totalTicks = 0;
    string avgticks = "";
    TimeSpan days = new TimeSpan();

    for (int i = 0; i < Dates.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < Dates.Count; j++)
        {
            days += (Dates[j] - Dates[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(days.TotalDays);
    Console.ReadLine();`
}
```

Comment: If the dates in the list is continuous, shouldn't the `total days` equal to the length of the list? And if they are not continuous, how do you define `total days`? Is it `(MaxDate - MinDate).TotalDays`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your dates in a list, why wouldn't some linq functions work?

```
days = Dates.Max() - Dates.Min();
Console.WriteLine(days.TotalDays);
```

I'm pretty sure given A < B < C,

(B - A) + (C - B) = C - A

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038771/get-total-days-in-a-list-of-dates-c-sharp) this one works with less code thank you.

Comment: if it works for you, you are welcome to mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

One loop is enough !
EDIT: I simplified even more.

```
public static void avgDate(List<DateTime> Dates) {
    long totalTicks = 0;
    string avgticks = "";
    TimeSpan days = new TimeSpan();

    for (int i = 1; i < Dates.Count; i++)
    {
        days += (Dates[i] - Dates[i-1]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(days.TotalDays);
    Console.ReadLine();`
```

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038771/get-total-days-in-a-list-of-dates-c-sharp thanks this one works but the second eliminates the loop, thank you